# How to reference a custom Identity field in ASP.NET Core Web Application?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

In my ASP.NET Core web application, I added custom fields in my Identity such as `CompanyCode` using `ApplicationUser` model. I am now trying to retrieve the `CompanyCode` of the current logged in user in the web application, but I do not know how to access this field. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, I suppose you have already added the CompanyCode to the ApplicationUser model, and configured the service and UserManager to use the ApplicationUser model. Like this:

UserManager:

```
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
```

Setup.cs ConfigureServices:

```
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Then, you could try to access the CompanyCode  field by using the following code:

```
@UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.CompanyCode
```

For example:

In the _LoginPartial.cshtml page:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @User.Identity.Name! @UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.CompanyCode</a>
</li>
```

After login, the result as below:

[image]

Or, in the controller action method:

```
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger; 
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger,  UserManager<ApplicationUser> usermanager)
    {
        _logger = logger; 
        _userManager = usermanager;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    { 
        if (this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        { 
            //login success
            var item = _userManager.GetUserAsync(this.User).Result.CompanyCode;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

The result like this:

[image]

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! Thank you so so much for your simple and direct answer!